# How do I make 25 requests at a time with HTTP::Async in Perl?

Tags: perl, http, asynchronous

I'm doing a lot of HTTP requests and I chose HTTP::Async to do the job. I've over 1000 requests to make, and if I simply do the following (see code below), a lot of requests time out by the time they get processed because it can take tens of minutes before processing gets to them:

```
for my $url (@urls) {
    $async->add(HTTP::Request->new(GET => $url));
}
while (my $resp = $async->wait_for_next_response) {
    # use $resp
}
```

So I decided to do 25 requests per time, but I can't think of a way to express it in code.

I tried the following:

```
while (1) {
    L25:
    for (1..25) {
        my $url = shift @urls;
        if (!defined($url)) {
            last L25;
        }
        $async->add(HTTP::Request->new(GET => $url));
    }
    while (my $resp = $async->wait_for_next_response) {
        # use $resp
    }
}
```

This however doesn't work well as because it's too slow now. Now it waits until all 25 requests have been processed until it adds another 25. So if it has 2 requests left, it does nothing. I've to wait for all requests to be processed to add the next batch of 25.

How could I improve this logic to make `$async` do something while I process records, but also make sure they don't time out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're close, you just need to combine the two approaches!  :-)

Untested, so think of it as pseudo code.  In particular I am not sure if `total_count` is the right method to use, the documentation doesn't say.  You could also just have an `$active_requests` counter that you `++` when adding a request and `--` when you get a response.

```
while (1) {

   # if there aren't already 25 requests "active", then add more
   while (@urls and $async->total_count < 25) {
       my $url = shift @urls;
       $async->add( ... );
   }

   # deal with any finished requests right away, we wait for a
   # second just so we don't spin in the main loop too fast.
   while (my $response = $async->wait_for_next_response(1)) {
      # use $response
   }

   # finish the main loop when there's no more work
   last unless ($async->total_count or @urls);

}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you can't call `wait_for_next_response` fast enough because you're in the middle of executing other code, the simplest solution is to make the code interruptable by moving it to a separate thread of execution. But if you're going to start using threads, why use HTTP::Async?

```
use threads;
use Thread::Queue::Any 1.03;

use constant NUM_WORKERS => 25;

my $req_q = Thread::Queue::Any->new();
my $res_q = Thread::Queue::Any->new();

my @workers;
for (1..NUM_WORKERS) {
   push @workers, async {
      my $ua = LWP::UserAgent->new();
      while (my $req = $req_q->dequeue()) {
         $res_q->enqueue( $ua->request($req) );
      }
   };    
}

for my $url (@urls) {
   $req_q->enqueue( HTTP::Request->new( GET => $url ) );
}

$req_q->enqueue(undef) for @workers;

for (1..@urls) {
   my $res = $res_q->dequeue();
   ...
}

$_->join() for @workers;
```

Comment: Hi ikegami, I try to run you sample code but unfortunately I receive follow message : 400 Can't locate object method "scheme" via package "URI::http - this is URI sheme issue but I use the right URI "http://www.web.de". you can find my source code in http://www.sourcepod.com/pqyyxw07-51950. thx

Comment: sorry, stackoverflow formatting my link. the link is: http:// www . web . de -> delete space char

Comment: but however I can use any other URLs and I receive same error. e-g http:// google . com

Comment: Successfully updated URI-1.64 (upgraded from 1.60) I test issue on fedora (x86_64 GNU/Linux) perl 5.16 and ubuntu (i686 athlon i386 GNU/Linux) perl 5.14. maybe I'm going to post a question for this bug

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/63705/discussion-between-ikegami-and-ovntatar).