# Why can't URI object locate method "scheme"?

Tags: multithreading, perl, http, asynchronous

I am trying to create an asynchronous http request client by using the following source code:

```
#!perl

use URI;
use DDP;
use threads;
use Thread::Queue;
use LWP::UserAgent;

use constant NUM_WORKERS => 25;

my $req_q = Thread::Queue->new();
my $res_q = Thread::Queue->new();

my @urls = ( "http://google.com", "http://web.de" );

my @workers;
for ( 1 .. NUM_WORKERS ) {
    push @workers, async {
        my $ua = LWP::UserAgent->new();
        while ( my $req = $req_q->dequeue() ) {
            $res_q->enqueue( $ua->request($req) );
        }
    };
}

for my $url (@urls) {
    $req_q->enqueue( HTTP::Request->new( GET => $url ) );
}

$req_q->enqueue(undef) for @workers;

for ( 1 .. @urls ) {
    my $res = $res_q->dequeue();
    p $res;
}

$_->join() for @workers;
```

Unfortunately I receive the error:

> `400 Can't locate object method "scheme" via package "URI::http"`

This should be a [`URI`](http://metacpan.org/pod/URI) module issue but if I use the URI package in other scripts it works fine.

I tried to upgrade URI to URI-1.64 (upgraded from 1.60) tested on fedora (x86_64 GNU/Linux) perl 5.16 and on ubuntu (i686 athlon i386 GNU/Linux) perl 5.14.

e.g

```
 $perl -MURI -E'say $INC{"URI.pm"}; say URI->VERSION; say URI->new("http://www.google.com/")->scheme'
 $/home/xxxxx/perl5/lib/perl5/URI.pm
 $1.64
 $http
```

Any idea what would be the best way to troubleshoot?

Comment: The error message is frustratingly terse. Is there any more to it?

Comment: the 400 output -> that's all

Comment: I'm using version LWP 6.08 and LWP::UserAgent 6.06

Comment: URI is dynamically loading other modules on demand, which maybe infers with threading (e.g. loaded in on thread, used in another). Try without threading or try to load URI::http explicitly before using any threads.

Comment: No line number? That is vexing...

Comment: Steffen I'm know you point of view and I realised that perl community have different suggestions to solve parallel processing, but in my case I want only to troubleshoot.

Comment: @LenJaffe there isn't line number.

Comment: It would be a good idea to `use strict; use warnings;` at the top of your script.

Answer (score 3):

The [original code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11173153/589924) used Thread::Queue::Any instead of Thread::Queue since it handles objects a bit better. However, there were two mistakes in the original code (now fixed).

```
use Thread::Queue::Any 1.03 qw( );
...
my $req_q = Thread::Queue->new();
my $res_q = Thread::Queue->new();
```

should be

```
use Thread::Queue::Any 1.03;  # Must call import.
...
my $req_q = Thread::Queue::Any->new();
my $res_q = Thread::Queue::Any->new();
```

Thread::Queue::Any does work in `import` that shouldn't be there, so my customary practice of not calling `import` backfired.

These minor changes will allow the code to work.

---

If wanted to continue using Thread::Queue, it looks like you have to load the modules of your shared objects before you call `use threads;` (I think that'll save you memory, so it's good idea to do no matter what.) URI dynamically loads URI::http, so you need to add

```
use URI::http;
```

or

```
BEGIN { URI->new('', 'http') }
```

before `use threads;`

That will get you passed that problem (and into another).

Comment: perfect @ikegami it works fine with Thread::Queue::Any 1.14 not with 1.03 -> however thx

Comment: 1.03 specifies a minimum. The code relies on a feature introduced in 1.03.

Comment: by using your suggestion with Thread::Queue and BEGIN { URI->new('', 'http') } the response content is: Can't locate object method "FETCH" via package "threads::shared::tie" at /usr/share/perl5/vendor_perl/HTTP/Headers.pm line 183. strange ..